# Web App has My.Application.Log instead of My.Log

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-3.5

According to the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172987.aspx), the My.Application.Log property is used to write log entries for client applications, and the My.Log property is used to write log entries for web applications.  However, I have a web application with a bunch of My.Application.Log calls in the .aspx.vb files.  These compile correctly, but if I change them to My.Log, I get compile errors.  Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this problem too.
This seems to happen when you write to log from a library (dll)
which is a sort of windows application.

Do you use a Dll?

Comment: Yes, I do.  That could explain it.